# Volume control is not working in HTML5 Video tag

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I am using html5 video tag in one of my website. Video is playing well but the volume button is disabled. And, clicking volume button makes no effect at all. The code used is very simple. Have a look at the code below:

```
<video class="class names goes here" controls>
<source type="video/ogg" src="videofilename.ogg"></source>
<source type="video/mp4" src="videofilename.mp4"></source>
<object data="videofilename.mp4"></object>
</video>
```

Even, I have tried to use jQuery function to increase the volume of video. But, failed.
Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see:

- if it works in another browser
- if the video's actual sound is working?

if there is any other reason for why it wouldn't work & would you consider embedding using 
a youtube link which works pretty well.

Comment: Video is having sound but the volume problem persists in every browser and even on every platform (Windows & Linux both).
YouTube embedding facility is also there in the website, but this functionality is also a requirement. However, audio tag is working well in the same project.

Comment: Please anyone suggest, is there a need of some jQuery to achieve this. W3C's specifications doesn't say that but still wants to confirm.